# nofollow in forums?

Tags: html, seo

I have a forum where people on a daily basis post links to other sites. At the moment the links are all "doFollow"

Will this hurt my Page Rank? And will I get a better Page Rank by making all these links "nofollow"?

Comment: `nofollow` is generally used to discourage spamming since it won't boost the PageRank of any sites posted by forum members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nofollow` will not affect your page rank.

I am sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

They don't hurt your pagerank, but they do boost the pagerank of the sites being linked to.